# Creating a hyperlink to a newly created lead record

Tags: sugarcrm

I am currently working on some custom programming. I dynamically create a lead when a Contact Us Wordpress form is submitted. The lead is created and an email is sent to the assigned salesperson. Is there anyway to add a hyperlink to this newly created lead, in the email body ?

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following sql snippet to create a link, it may give you a pointer?

`SET @url = 'https://example.com/index.php?module=Contact&action=DetailView&record='; 
SELECT 
    id AS 'ID', 
    CONCAT(@url,id) AS 'Link', 
    t_position.deleted AS 'Deleted' 
FROM 
    contacts 
WHERE
    contacts.deleted = 0;`

Hope that helps some.